# How can I decrease the import time of openpyxl?

Tags: python, anaconda, openpyxl

Why is the import time on openpyxl so long? I've tried multiple other packages and all of their import times are significantly lower than openpyxl. Im using NINJA-IDE and Anaconda. Below is an output from line_profiler.

```
Timer unit: 4.10923e-07 s
Total time: 48.7025 s
Function: combine at line 5

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

 5                                           def combine():
 7         1    117359903 117359903.0     99.0      import openpyxl
```

Comment: One is a collection of 20 or so functions, the other is an API for Excel files. The import only takes about 10 seconds on my system, about as long as `scipy.stats`.

Comment: Import os is not there for comparison reasons. Ill edit the post and remove that to mitigate confusion.The import for openpyxl alone takes 40+ seconds on my computer which is what I am inquiring about.

Comment: Why the downvote?  OP -- the module has to read the registry to find some information reg. which version of Office/Excel is installed.  The bigger the registry, the longer it takes to load.